# Android Studio Custom Listview need to be displayed on fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

Currently I'm attempting to make a custom list view for my application which I have succeed with. But the issue I have is that if I place the list view onto my main activity then the list view works as planned displaying both text and images. But with my application I have the ability to swipe between pages and instead of having this list view permanently on my main activity page I want it on a fragment page e.g. WineList page and when the user swipes to the next page you can know longer see it

If I attempt to change the list view to one which is on a fragment page then I get a null exception error which is understandable because I'm guessing the page hasn't been made until the user swipes across.

I have included the image below to demonstrate what I mean.

[Listview on Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C4aR.png)

my application set up

Custom adapter class --

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, names);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater hadleighsInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = hadleighsInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    String singleName = getItem(position);
    TextView hadleighText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.hadleighText);
    ImageView hadleighImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.myimageView);

    hadleighText.setText(singleName);
    hadleighImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageresize);
    return  customView;




}
}
```

Main Activity --

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainwindow);





    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.swipeView);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

  //  Currently set up to the list view on the main activity


    String[] names = {"Hadleigh", "james", "LOLLLO"};
    ListAdapter hadleighsAdapter = new socialdeveloper.adgestonevineyard.CustomAdapter(this,names);
    ListView hadleighsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListview);
    hadleighsListView.setAdapter(hadleighsAdapter);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabSwipe);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }
```

WineList Fragment  (Which I wish to display my listview on)-----

```
public class WineList extends Fragment{




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.winelist, container, false);


}



}
```

So basically its currently on the main activity but I don't know which changes I have to implement to display it on the fragment page instead.

[Example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFGZW.png)

Comment: If this is your Fragment -> WineList  where you want to show your listview then simply add ListView in it and thats all !! also create view object by inflate and then return it

Comment: I can add a listview to the wine list XML and then on the direct it on the main activity class. Could you give an example of how I edit my code?

Comment: For some reason unable to put answer on this website

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `Fragment`'s in your `ViewPager` - use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).
Create Layout with `ListView` for your `Fragment`.
Create static method for new instance of your `Fragment` with some parameter. Using this parameter you can set adapter with different values to `ListView` in current `Fragment`.

---

If it's to complicated for you, follow [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/).
Just replace `ImageView` with `ListView` and implement the idea above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this complete code as well ! It works for what i see in your example image.

First, add this to the build.gradle

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
```

**WineListActivity**

```
    //imports
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class WineListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ViewPager viewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_winelist);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            if (viewPager != null) {
                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
            }

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        }


        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new InformationFragment(), "INFORMATION");
            adapter.addFragment(new HomeWebsitesFragment(), "LISTVIEW");
            adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "HOME");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

            public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragments.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitles.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragments.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragments.size();
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
            }
        }
}
```

Xml layout, **activity_winelist**

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bdc3c7"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Your list Fragment,  **ListFragment**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;

    public static ListFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        String[] values = new String[] { "wine 1", "wine 2", "wine 3",
               "wine 4" };

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
           list.add(values[i]);
       }

        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, list);
        if(list.size() == 0){
            listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyview));
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Your list, list.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Your adapter, **MySimpleArrayAdapter**

```
    public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> values;


            public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
                super(context, -1, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            textView.setText(values.get(position));

            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

And then you can add your two other Fragments and do what ever you wish with them.

**HomeFragment**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
        private int mPage;

        public static HomeFragment newInstance(int page) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            return view;
        }

    }
```

**InformationFragment**

```
    public class InformationFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
        private int mPage;

        public static InformationFragment newInstance(int page) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
            InformationFragment fragment = new InformationFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container, false);
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello Html Tosin it has been very helpful currently i'm getting a tone of errors trying to get everything put together. Could you send me your android file if that isn't too much to ask just so I can work from it? I'm still a beginner :D

Comment: Ok, i will edit my code to make it easier , which errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm mainly getting errors when building the fragment pages as it's not recognizing the findViewById  sections. been stuck on this problem since 11am nows its 17.32

Comment: You can join me in this room, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107875/viewpager-temporary-issue